# Find if value is contained in comma separated values in JS

Tags: javascript, string

Given these two strings:

```
var first = 'dog,cat,lion';
var second = 'cat';
```

How would I do it to know if the second var is any of the words (the ones that are separated by commas) in the first vars?

Comment: case sensitive? will you always have a single word within the commas?  must the second word ("cat") be exactly matched or do you want to obtain any word with the sequence "cat"? i.e. "cute cat", "catalog", "scatter"... starts with, ends with, contains???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would work:

```
if( first.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+second+"(?:,|$)"))) {
    // it's there
}
```

Comment: Kolink, would it be really difficult if I would need to take into account that the first string can contain spaces after or before the commas, like "dog, cat, lion"?

Comment: Nope. Just use `\s*` wherever there may be optional space. The only real complication is that if `second` contains any special regex characters, they'll mess up the search. You should try something like [`preg_quote`](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/) from PHPJS.

Comment: Well, In my case its just causing small error:
`requirement:csv,doc,docx,html,htm,jpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pps,rtf,sww,tab,txt,text,tsv,xls,xlsx`
`fileExtension:png`
but returning false because return value ',png,' which is not correct
to resolve it
`requirement.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+fileExtension+"(?:,|$)")).replace(/,\s+/g, ',')`

Answer (score 29):

You can use `Array.indexOf`:

```
if( first.split(',').indexOf(second) > -1 ) {
   // found
}
```

Need IE8- support? Use a shim: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Niet's solution is beautifully elegant, but many developers are not comfortable with regex.  So I prefer this one for practical reasons.  Many of the others do the same thing as this, but with many more lines of code.  Nice work David!

Answer (score 1):

First, split your String to an array:

```
var second = 'cat';
var first = 'dog,cat,lion';
var aFirst = first.split(',');
```

Then cycle through your new array

```
for (var i = 0; i < aFirst.length; i++) {
    if (aFirst[i] == second) {
        alert('jay!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var first = 'dog,cat,lion';
var stringArray = first.split(',');       
for (var i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++) {
    if (stringArray[i].match("cat")) {
          alert('Its matched');
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = 'dog, cat, lion';
var second = 'cat';
// \b is a word boundary
// a word character, \w, consists of letters, digits and underscore
// remove the second paramater "i" if you want case-sensitive match
var containsRE = new RegExp(second, "i"); 
var startsWithRE = new RegExp("\\b"+second, "i"); 
var endsWithRE = new RegExp(second+"\\b", "i"); 
var exactRE = new RegExp("\\b"+second+"\\b", "i"); 
// test exactRE, for example, like so
if(exactRE.test(first)) {
    // matched
}
```