# Match or search string by comma separated values by jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to match/search string partially by js array to a string. my string and array example are below

```
var str = "host, gmail, yahoo";
var search = 'new@gmail.com';
```

i already tried as below:

```
if( str.split(',').indexOf(search) > -1 ) {
   console.log('Found');
}
```

It should match with `gmail` for string `new@gmail.com`

i am using this with reference of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313857/2384642

Comment: Why to use `jQuery` for this task ? As jQuery is used for `DOM` manipulation tasks.

Comment: @ths use js or jQuery, anything

Comment: @ShivSingh indexOf will check for an exact match in the array. You are trying to match a part of the string, try using regex

Comment: Yes @Varun i know that but how to reg

Comment: @ShivSingh This is without regex but you will have to change it depending if you need the position of the match or the value
https://jsfiddle.net/k6x9ncq8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues here. Firstly, your input string has spaces after the comma, yet you're splitting by *just* the comma hence you'd get `' gmail'` as a value, which would break the `indexOf()` result. Either remove the spaces, or use `split(', ')`.

Secondly, you need to loop through the resulting array from the `split()` operation and check each value in the `search` string individually. You're also currently using `indexOf()` backwards, ie. you're looking for `new@gmail.com` within `gmail`. With these issues in mind, try this:

```js
var str = "host,gmail,yahoo";
var search = 'new@gmail.com';

str.split(',').forEach(function(host) {
  if (search.indexOf(host) != -1) {
    console.log('Found');
  }
});
```

Also note that you could define the array of hosts explicitly and avoid the need to `split()`:

```js
var hosts = ['host', 'gmail', 'yahoo'];
var search = 'new@gmail.com';

hosts.forEach(function(host) {
  if (search.indexOf(host) != -1) {
    console.log('Found');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the `split` method returns an array, you'd have to iterate through that array and check for matchs.

Here's a demo:

```js
// added gmail.com to the string so you can see more matched results(gmail and gmail.com).
var str = "host, gmail, yahoo, gmail.com",
search = 'new@gmail.com',
splitArr = str.replace(/(\,\s+)/g, ',').split(','),
/* the replace method above is used to remove whitespace(s) after the comma. The str variable stays the same as the 'replace' method doesn't change the original strings, it returns the replaced one. */
l = splitArr.length,
i = 0;

for(; i < l; i++) {
  if(search.indexOf(splitArr[i]) > -1 ) {
   console.log('Found a match: "' + splitArr[i] + '" at the ' + i + ' index.\n');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It should match with gmail for string new@gmail.com

In order to achieve your result you need to extract **gmail** from the search string.

You can achieve this with regex:

```
search.match( /\S+@(\S+)\.\S+/)[1]
```

```js
var str = "host, gmail, yahoo, qwegmail";
var search = 'new@gmail.com';

if( str.split(', ').indexOf(search.match( /\S+@(\S+)\.\S+/)[1]) > -1 ) {
    console.log(search + ': Found');
} else {
    console.log(search + ': Not found');
}


search = 'asd@qwegmail.com';

if( str.split(', ').indexOf(search.match( /\S+@(\S+)\.\S+/)[1]) > -1 ) {
    console.log(search + ': Found');
} else {
    console.log(search + ': Not found');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but your answer is working for only *@gmail.com, but i am want to match from anywhere like asdgmail@asd.com or asd@qwegmail.com or asd@asegmailase.com

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, none substring in `str` contains `search` value. So you need to invert the logic. something like this.

```js
var str = "host, gmail, yahoo";
var search = 'new@gmail.com';
var res = str.split(', ').filter(function(el) {
  return search.indexOf(el) > -1;
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Array with this code so you don't need to separate it with the ','

```
var str = new Array ("host","gmail","yahoo");
```

To find the element, use something this

```
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
    {
         val = str[i];
         if (val.substring(0) === "gmail")
         {
              res = val;
              break;
         }
    }
    //Use res (result) here
```

Note: This is my first answer, so plese forgive me if there are some errors...